# I was ordering donuts at a Korean donut shop. How do I order?

Tags: word-choice, numbers

I jump at every chance to practice Korean and the store clerk was speaking Korean to the previous customer so I tried my best.

After greeting with "안녕하세요" and then fielding questions on how I know Korean, haha. I said "12(십이) 주세요." Is that formal enough to order from an older lady?

Then, when specifying which ones I wanted, she asked me "둘개?", "세개?", or "네개?"

But, why did she use the other number system? And, did I use the correct number system originally?

Comment: you should use 하나, 둘, 셋, 넷, ... for counting items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that formal enough to order from an older lady?

Yes, it is and that's how you do it whenever you order something.

> why did she use the other number system?

First of all, excuse me for not knowing the exact name for this system. But I know that this is the numbering system you use for *counting*.

> 12 pencils = 연필 열 두자루
>   12 trees = 나무 열 두그루
>   12 cats = 고양이 열 두마리
>   12 donuts = 도넛 열 두개

Frankly, if you mixed up the numbering system we would still understand but technically your usage was not correct.

The other numbering system is generally used when your doing math.

> 2 x 3 = 이 곱하기 삼
>   2x - 3 = 이 엑스 빼기 삼
>   -2 + 3 = 마이너스 이 더하기 삼
>   2/3 = 삼 분의 이
>   2.3 = 이 점 삼

... and, when your counting days.

> I'll come back in three days = 삼 일 뒤에 돌아오겠습니다.

... or you can use a whole new numbering system for days!

> 1 = 하루
>   2 = 이틀
>   3 = 사흘
>   4 = 나흘*
>   5 = 닷새*
>   6 = 엿새*
>   7 = 이레*
>   8 = 여드레*
>   9 = 아흐레*
>   10 = 열흘
>   (marked with * means not used often)

But what happens after 10 days? You go back to the math numbering system.

> 십 일일, 이 십일, ...

... and weeks are a little weird too.

> I'll see you in a week. = 일 주(일) 뒤에 봐요.
>   The task is likely going to take 6 weeks. = 그 일은 아마 육 주(일) 정도 걸릴거예요.

It's funny because if you use the counting system, you end up talking about stocks.

> I just bought 7 shares from Apple. 나 방금 애플 주식을 일곱 주를 샀어.

But everything goes back to normal with months. Phew!

> After 1 month = 한 달 뒤
>   Within 20 months = 스무 달 안에

But beware, years are here to mess with you just one more time.

> After 1 year = 일 년 뒤
>   Within 20 years = 이십 년 안에

When we're talking time, remember that only the *hours* follow the counting scheme and everything else, the math scheme.

> After an hour = 한 시간 뒤에
>   After two hours and a half = 두 시간 반 뒤에
>   Within two and a quarter hours = 두 시간 십 오분 안에

You can think of it as, anything from and below than "minutes" is considered as a unit of *measurement* like "nanoseconds", or "kilometers," but hours are treated as units of time-things.

But the measurements can get a little tricky, too. We use the counting scheme for traditional measures but the math scheme for western ones.

> 한 근, 두 척, 세 뼘, ...
>   일 피트, 이 킬로미터, 삼 뉴튼, ...

Finally, ages. When you're counting ages you use the counting scheme for "살" but the math scheme for "세".

> 한 살, 두 살, ...
>   만 한 살, 만 두 살...
>
> Kids under 5 cannot enter here. = 만 오 세 이하 영•유아는 이 곳에 들어올 수 없습니다.
>   Louis XIV = 루이 십 사세

In writing, we of course prefer using Arabic numbers to writing then out.

Whelp, so yeah counting in Korean can get very messy... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> And, did I use the correct number system originally?

No, you use native numbers with 개. 한 개, 두 개, 세 개, ...

You should have said 열두 개 주세요 instead of 십이 주세요.